# Attach PersistentVolume in a new node in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I try to describe my scenario:

I have a MariaDB from bitnami installed in an EKS Kubernetes cluster.
I'm deploying my database using helm with the following command

```
helm install mariadb bitnami/mariadb \
     --set primary.persistence.enabled=true \
     --set primary.persistence.size=1Gi
```

- This command creates a PVC in my environment.
- The problem comes when every night I destroy the node in order to save money.
- I reduce the ASG to 0 and then the node is destroyed.
- Every morning I extend de ASG to 1, and then a new node is created, my MariaDB is deployed but doesn't attach the PVC.

Is there any way to get the volume could attach again to a new node every day?

Thanks

**SOLUTION**

The problem was the AZ where my node and the volumen were created in every recreation, because I'm using multi-AZ. In my case, as is development environment, I forced to use just one AZ and the problem is fixed.

Comment: EKS should come with a persistent volume provisioner that creates EBS volumes; while these can only be attached to one node at a time, they can be moved, and the cluster knows how to do that.  Does the PersistentVolume exist?  Do you see it mounted in the resulting Pod spec?

Comment: Yes, the PV exist, and in the first deploy, before the node is destroyed, is attached in the node. But when the node is recreated I get this error in the pod:

0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get back the volume because the node you launched every morning is not guaranteed to be in the same AZ as yesterday; which the volume was last created. Switch to single AZ will work for you as you only need to launch one node everyday. On the console goto the ASG and edit the Network -> Availability Zones.

Comment: True, this is the correct answer. I just discover that the problem is exactly the AZ. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is there another way with any kind of affinity to configure the volume to atach in any node

Comment: How about starting a new question so that this question remain focus and accurate. Happy to address your question there.

Answer (score 0):

Your volume is not begin persistent because it is not attached to an underlying volume in AWS.

Please have a look into attaching a EBS or EFS to eks node

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-persistent-storage/

Comment: I've already read this doc but didn't give me any clue for the problem : /

Comment: The problem is that you don't have a EBS or EFS connected to your PVC. If you delete your node your EC2 instance will get deleted so you data will be gone.

Comment: I don't think so.. If I delete my helm chart and I recreate my EKS node, the pvc and pv are 'alive'. Then if I deploy again the helm release using this argument: --set primary.persistence.existingClaim="pv-name", the volume is attached to the mariadb pod with no problems.. @Lucasz